# What is a good individual representation for a closed path planning task using genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, genetic-algorithm

There is a n*n grid and in one of the cells of the grid lies an agent A. 
A can travel T number of cells.

Each cell in the grid has some weight and the path for A has to maximize that weight.

A also has to return to its starting position within its traveling range T.

What can be a good individual representation to represent the paths?

Methods I have tried:

1. Chromosome is a list of coordinates.
2. Chromosome is a list of directions. Each gene is a direction like up, down, up-right, etc. Path never breaks in the middle.

Problems with both methods is that crossing-over almost always generates invalid paths. Paths become broken in the middle. They don't form a closed path. I can't seem to figure out a good way to represent the individual solution and an appropriate crossing-over method. Please help.

Comment: The first one makes more sense for me than the second one

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would say that this problem is a better fit for other approaches, such as maybe [ant colony optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms), greedy approaches that give good enough solutions etc. GAs might not work so well for the exact reason you describe.

However, if you must use GAs, here are two possible models that might be worth investigating:

1. Severely punish invalid paths by giving invalid moves a cost of -infinity. For example, if your chromosome says go from a cell `x` to an unreachable cell `y`, consider the cost of `y` -infinity. This might be worth combining with a low probability of crossover happening, something like 5% maybe.
2. Don't do crossover, just do some form of more involved mutation of the offspring.

If you want to get even fancier, this is somewhat similar to the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which has a lot of research in relation to genetic algorithms:

http://www.lalena.com/AI/Tsp/

http://www.math.hmc.edu/seniorthesis/archives/2001/kbryant/kbryant-2001-thesis.pdf

Comment: actually I decided to use GA because a lot of papers are available on the internet that provide some way of getting from point A to point B in a map and getting the optimal path for that using GA. What makes my problem different is that I don't necessarily want the shortest path. I want to maximize the wights in the cells the path covers, while keeping the total length of the path under the maximum range of the agent.

Comment: I'm currently taking some inspiration from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23042457/1446808)

Comment: Note that advice 1. can cause the fitness landscape to become extremely jagged, depending on the amount of invalid paths you have in your problem. The search process could potentially deteriorate to a random search. If you can, you should try to derive some meaningful information from the invalid path (a measure of invalidity as opposed to a dichotomous classification would be good). I'd also try an ACO approach, as the representation of your problem in a GA can be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You could encode the path as a reference list:
Assume these are your locations `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)`
A subset route of `(1 2 3 4 8)` could be encoded `(1 1 2 1 4)`.

Now take two parents

`p1 = (1 1 2 1 | 4 1 3 1 1)
p2 = (5 1 5 5 | 5 3 3 2 1)`

which will produce

`o1 = (1 1 2 1 5 3 3 2 1)
o2 = (5 1 5 5 4 1 3 1 1)`

which will be decoded into these location routes

`o1 = 1 – 2 – 4 – 3 – 9 – 7 – 8 – 6 – 5
o2 = 5 – 1 – 7 – 8 – 6 – 2 – 9 – 3 – 4`

This way, a crossover will always yield valid results (whether this representation will help you solving your problem better is a different question).

Some additional information can be found [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=657094).